# How do I reduce the space allocated for Persistent Storage on my Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, liveusb, persistent

I used Rufus to create a Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Live USB with persistence. However, I allocated all of the remaining drive space for the Persistent Storage, thinking that it could be accessed and used as a normal USB Drive partition (which is not the case).

To reduce the space allocated for persistence, do I just reduce the partition size or are there other steps?

Comment: Just create it again with less than 100% used for persistence. That said, the persistent partition *must* be writable to allow changes to the OS!